# Check if exception is thrown in try..catch..finally

Tags: python-2.7, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, d):
            try:
                    self.row_number = 1
                    self.name = d['name']
                    self.address = d['address']
                    self.__err_flag = 0
            except Exception, ex:
                    self.__err_flag = 1
            finally:
                    self.val = ex.message if self.__err_flag else None
```

The only purpose of `self.__err_flag` is to check if an exception was caught. I obviously cannot have the condition: `self.val = ex.message if ex else None`.

Is there a better way to check if an exception was caught in the finally block? Also, when I do following:

```
t = Test({'name': 'kitty-katty'})
dir(t) // print _Test__err_flag
```

Is there a way to hide attributes of a class so that they don't show up when doing `dir()`?

Comment: Your "how do I check if an exception is thrown?" and "how do I hide attributes?" questions seem to be unrelated. Please ask them in separate posts.

Comment: I don't think you can hide anything from `dir`. Python doesn't have explicit private fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want `self.val` to be assigned when an exception occurs, put the assignment in the `except` instead of the `finally`.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, d):
            self.val = None
            try:
                    self.row_number = 1
                    self.name = d['name']
                    self.address = d['address']
            except Exception, ex:
                    self.val = ex.message
```

Comment: I would prefer those attributes to be present for all instances of `Test` that are created. I generally hate doing `has_attr()` for instance of my classes. EDIT: Missed your line: `self.val = None`

Comment: Which attributes? The `val` attribute? You can assign a None to it at the start of your `__init__` and then give it something more meaningful if an exception occurs.